How to make the animation expand upward when using Modifier.animateContentSize() in Jetpack Compose?
I'm trying to make a layout, in this case a Column, expand upward vertically on the press of a button. It's not working. It's only expanding downward.
When launched it displays a dark gray column. The column has a width of 200.dp and a height of 0.dp. Below it is a Button. When The Button is clicked it will cause the Column to expand to 200.dp in height:
@Composable
fun ExpandingColumn() {
    var expanded by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .offset(
                    x = 70.dp,
                    y = 250.dp,
                )
                .animateContentSize()
                .background(color = Color.DarkGray)
                .width(200.dp)
                .height(if (expanded) 200.dp else 0.dp)
        ) {

        }
        Button(
            onClick = { expanded = !expanded },
            modifier = Modifier
                .offset(
                    x = 150.dp,
                    y = 600.dp
                ),
        ) {
            Text(text = "Click")
        }
    }
}

The problem is whenever the column expands it animates downward. I want the animation to go upward.

I think there's no straightforward way of achieving what you want to do, because in case of animateContentSize it always animates between sizes and due to the nature of drawing that exists on the Android OS, it always draws content in the downward direction, i.e. positive Y axis.
So if you're animating, it will always animate downwards
There's one way of doing what you want to do, and it is described as below
Use a dummy layout, Column in this case, and render it exactly on top of your already existing layout Column in this case. Make sure, that the dimensions of the overlayed layout and the underlayed layout are same, for nice views
After this, you would reduce the size of the overlayed layout, based on the expanded state. I have renamed this state to shrunk indicating the shrunk state of the overlay layout. I have also used animateDpAsState which lets you animate between two Dp values very easily. Take a look at the code here
        // State to indicate overlay visibility
        var shrunk by remember {
            mutableStateOf(true)
        }
        // Height of the overlay layout
        val height = animateDpAsState(
            targetValue = if (shrunk) 200.dp else 0.dp,
            animationSpec = tween(
                2000,
                easing = FastOutSlowInEasing
            ),
            label = "height"
        )
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(Color.White)
        ) {
           // Layout which needs animation
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .offset(
                        x = 70.dp,
                        y = 250.dp,
                    )
                    .background(color = Color.DarkGray)
                    .width(200.dp)
                    .height(200.dp)
            ) {

            } 
    
            //Overlay layout, with same dimensions as underlay
    
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .offset(
                        x = 70.dp,
                        y = 250.dp,
                    )
                    // Note: Same background as the container Box
                    .background(color = Color.White)
                    .width(200.dp)
                    .height(height.value)
            ) {

            }


            Button(
                onClick = { shrunk = !shrunk },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .offset(
                        x = 150.dp,
                        y = 600.dp
                    ),
            ) {
                Text(text = "Click")
            }
        }
    }

Adding a preview here
